# jQuery Cycle IE 8 PNG issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, png, cycle

Ok guys, why doesn't IE8 support PNGs when using cycle and how can we get around this, have been looking for a solution for months and getting nowhere.. big probs to the solver of this one...

Example : http://mdcontrols.co.uk/ - check in IE9 then IE8 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cleartype: true
cleartypeNoBg: true

- Has fixed this issue